# How to paste a division in Excel, not actually divide it

Tags: vba, ms-access

In VBA I am doing

```
cell = cstr(numerator) & "/" & cstr(denominator)
```

cell is a cell in an excel workbook

Hoping it'll look like a ranking, "23/167"

but instead it's just performing a division and outputting a number. How do I force it to output the whole thing as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tick in front indicates to Excel that the value is text.

```
cell = "'" & cstr(numerator) & "/" & cstr(denominator)
```

Alternatively you could format the cell as text before you export.

```
cell.NumberFormat = "@"
cell = cstr(numerator) & "/" & cstr(denominator)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `'` at the front of the string

Answer (score 1):

I bet it will look like a date from time to time also.

Try this:

```
cell.NumberFormat = "@"
cell.Value = cell = cstr(numerator) & "/" & cstr(denominator)
```